# PHP login- If statement execute even if there is no match

Tags: php, authentication

I am new to PHP, I created a login method. When I submit the data even if the value doesn't match the "if" statement is being executed

My code:

```
<?php
  // include db configuration
  include("./config.php");

  // converting data to JSON
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  //assigning input to variables
  $user_name = $data->user_name;
  $password  = hash( 'sha256', $data->password );
  $tokenUser  = hash( 'sha256', $data->user_name );

  //checking username and password
  $getUserInfo = $db->query("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND password='$password'");

  //getting user information
  $getUserInfo = $getUserInfo->fetchAll();

  $token;

  if (count($getUserInfo == 1))
  {
      //creating a token for user authentication
      $token = $tokenUser . " | " . uniqid() . uniqid() . uniqid();

      $q = "UPDATE user SET token=:token WHERE user_name=:user_name AND password=:password";

      $query = $db->prepare($q);

      $execute = $query->execute(array(
          ":token" => $token,
          ":user_name" => $user_name,
          ":password" => $password
      ));

      $response = array(
          'user_name' => $user_name,
          'token' => $token,
          'access' => 'Granted'
      );

      echo json_encode($response);
  }
  else
  {
      $error = array(
          'status' => 'error',
          'message' => 'Username or Password is invlid'
      );
      echo json_encode($error);
  }

?>
```

how to validate this, is the code correct, need some clarification

Comment: `if (count($getUserInfo == 1))` should be as follows: if `(count($getUserInfo) == 1)`

Comment: @HassanAhmed - You should post it as an answer.

Comment: You hash the username as well as the password?  Why?  Usernames usually aren't considered sensitive.

Comment: okay I will try that @HassanAhmed

Comment: until i develop, I need a reference of user name, so I kept as it is. thanks@GordonM

Comment: @HassanAhmed. I worked. Could You post that as an answer I will close this question.

Comment: Instead of using your own hashing algorithm, you should use PHP's tried and tested [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Okay, I will try that too... Thanks @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
if (count($getUserInfo == 1))
```

should be as follows:

```
if (count($getUserInfo) == 1)
```

Comment: that was a rookie mistake I made :)